# To print line before matched pattern

Tags: awk

I need to print a line before the matched pattern.
Example: I have a file like this,

File is

```
test file: file1
labalanalma
kaknalknala
user: xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyyxy
djkdhjkh:whwejewj
jwjkewhjkwe: jkdwhjdweh
etc
etc:etc
Jndwejklhewljk
pattern1: Found
wkjhwekwj
wkjhwekj
```

I want to print "pattern1: Found" and "user: xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyyxy" ( first search for "pattern1: Found" if its there then only print line starting from user. This is AIX and not Linux so `grep -B` will not work here.

Comment: This might work: `sed -n '/^user:/,/pattern1: Found/{p;q}'  file`

Comment: @Cyrus will this work? What if there are two lines with user? or no `pattern1: Found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your `user` match in a variable and print it:

```
$ awk '/user:/{u=$0}/pattern/{print $0; print u}' file
pattern1: Found
user: xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyyxy
```

Answer (score 0):

This Perl one-liner would work..

```
$  perl -ne ' $x=$_ if /user:/; print "$_$x" if /pattern1:/ ' match.txt
pattern1: Found
user: xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyyxy

$
```